# Legitimate Proxy Service Providers?

Tags: proxy

I have a friend of mine who is a businessman currently residing in Turkey. He does business here in the US and spends considerable time here in States. He heard about the streaming services that will be launched soon and want to set it up in his ps3 and stream the videos through his netflix account. As far as i know the service is not open outside the US.

- Would it be possible to use a fast proxy to do this. Is there any "REPUTABLE" proxy server/service providers providing fast, secure, reliable service here in the US?

Answer (score 0):

use Ultra Surf. Just check out this site. Maybe this will help. [Ultra Surf](http://www.ultrareach.com/)